# Why can't I access a directory even though I'm in the owner group?

Tags: permissions, directory

So there's a user `rtorrent:torrent` which is in group `media-agent`.

Here is the command I'm trying to get working:

```
rtorrent@seedbox:/shared/storage$ cd books
bash: cd: books: Permission denied
```

Even though the folder has permission 664:

```
rtorrent@seedbox:/shared/storage$ ls -al
total 44
drwxrwxrwx 11 media-agent media-agent 4096 Aug 15 15:05 .
drwxrwxrwx  8 root        root        4096 Aug 15 01:12 ..
drw-rw-r--  3 media-agent media-agent 4096 Aug 15 15:15 books
drw-rw-r--  2 media-agent media-agent 4096 Aug 15 15:03 cartoons
drw-rw-r--  4 media-agent media-agent 4096 Aug 15 01:10 games
drw-rw-r--  3 media-agent media-agent 4096 Aug 15 00:47 libraries
drw-rw-r--  5 media-agent media-agent 4096 Aug 12 16:54 media-center
drw-rw-r--  2 media-agent media-agent 4096 Aug  6 15:31 other
drw-rw-r--  8 media-agent media-agent 4096 Aug 15 01:10 personnal
drw-rw-r--  5 media-agent media-agent 4096 Aug 15 01:10 software
drw-rw-r--  2 media-agent media-agent 4096 Aug  6 18:38 sync
```

Here is the group setup:

```
rtorrent@seedbox:/shared/storage$ getent group | grep 'media-agent'
torrent:x:1005:vinz243,www-data,ftpuser,media-agent,nodejs,rtorrent
media-agent:x:1007:vinz243,plex,deluge,rtorrent,root,nodejs
nodejs:x:1008:media-agent
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To be able to `cd` into a directory you need `x` permissions.  Your `books` directory doesn't have that:

```
drw-rw-r--  3 media-agent media-agent 4096 Aug 15 15:15 books
```

Indeed none of those directories have `x` permissions.

You can recursively fix permissions with something like

```
find . -type d -exec chmod a+x {} \;
```

You may need to be the `media-agent` user (or `root`) to do that.

Answer (score 4):

```
chmod g+x books
```

Executable flags for directories mean listing.